# How to open the libgdx project generator?

Tags: windows-7, java

I'm new here, new to libgdx, new to java, new...
And I just want to open the libgdx project generator, I tried to open it with java(tm) se binary but a window open and close instantly and I really don't know why.I tried by the cmd ( java -jar gfx-setup.jar ) and it answered me: 'unable to access jarfile gfx-setup.jar'

I know it's a really easy matter to solve, it's just a simple thing that I don't understand but after hours of looking for the answer I don't find anithing that help me so I came here because I don't know where to go anymore. Sorry for loosing your time but PLEASE !!!

PS: sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

- Open it with javaw
- change you command to use javaw instead of java
- Make a Bat file and use : `start javaw -jar gdx-setup.jar`